# Rails: What is the best way to only display a line when not empty in html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**PART 1:** The below code seems to work fine, but there must be a better way to do the second line. This is to display a user address. It is pretty simple, where if there is content for the second line of an address, I output that and a line break.

```
      <%= @sponsor.address1 %><br />
      <%= raw "#{@sponsor.address2} <br />" unless @sponsor.address2.empty? %>
      <%= @sponsor.city %>, <%= @sponsor.state %> <%= @sponsor.zip %>
```

Is there some obvious, more elegant way to do this?

**PART 2:** What if the value may also be nil? Should I handle that in the model? Is there some simple way to have a model return blank instead of nil?

Nesting this in yet another condition seems too messy. Can someone tell me the best rails way to accomplish part 1 and/or 2 above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Few more options if you want to make the div conditional too;

```
<%= content_tag :div do -%>
  @sponsor.address2
<% end if @sponsor.address2? -%>
```

or

```
<%= content_tag :div, @sponsor.address2 if @sponsor.address2? %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I deal with addresses a lot and this is my preferred method for fields that are often blank. Good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work the best of answers thus far. Even this is a little long for such a simple thing. I may want to pull that out into a helper.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of dealing with raw, you can use the tag helper for the `<br/>`

```
<%= @sponsor.address2 + tag('br') if @sponsor.address2? %>
```

Comment: funny enough when I was reminding myself of syntax for content_for - it referenced tag and I was wondering what the use case might be, but you've used it here. nice!

Comment: Thanks. I like that this is pretty concise, but (in rails 3) it escaped the <br />.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div>
  <%= @sponsor.address1 %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= @sponsor.address2 if @sponsor.address2? %>
</div>
```

This should handle both `nil?` and `empty?` cases.

You can style divs if you wan't to. By default the should render above each other. If `address2?` returs false, there will be just an empty div of 0px height that cannot be seen.